# Google Maps испортил проект

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Пробовал использовать карты от гугла, результат меня не устроил я удалил activity, и класс разметки. После чего в проекте появилась ошибка.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   C:\Prodshect\quickstart-android-master\240417gid\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml

Error:(1820, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'metaButtonBarButtonStyle'.

Error:(1819, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'metaButtonBarStyle'.

Error:(1820, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'metaButtonBarButtonStyle'.

Error:(1819, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'metaButtonBarStyle'.

```
   <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Я в панике, подскажите как лечить.

Comment: Попробуйте rebuild сделать

Comment: Пробовал, все так же неизменно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему удалением всех строк связанных с этими переменными из файла `styles.xml`